# Positive-Semidefiniteness of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Under the rule that a matrix is *positive semidefinite* if all its principal minors are nonnegative.

So, I have:
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -4 \\ -4 & 8 \end{bmatrix} $$

By an eigenvalue test, $\lambda_{1,2} = 0, 10$, so A is PSD.

However, is $-4$ not a principal minor thus violating the rule?

Answer (score 2):

The principal minors are those obtained by removing the **same** rows and columns. Therefore, the principal minors of order 1 of your matrix are
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \end{pmatrix},\quad\mbox{and}\quad \begin{pmatrix} 8 \end{pmatrix}.$$
You get the former by removing the first row and first column; you get the latter by removing the second row and second column.

For positive-definiteness, you would then have to restrict to *leading* principal minors, which are minors you get by removing the last $k$ rows and last $k$ columns. Therefore, the only leading principal minors are
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \end{pmatrix},\quad\mbox{and}\quad \begin{pmatrix} 2 & -4\\ -4 & 8\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Hmmm, I have two definitions: $A$ is positive-definite if all *leading* principal minors are positive, i.e. > 0. Then $A$ is PSD if all principal minors are nonnegative.

Comment: @clocktower Sorry, you're right. I mixed up my definitions... I will update my answer.